# Suppose that $f(z)$ is meromorphic on a disk, show that negative powers in the Laurent series of $f(z)$ is the sum of the principal parts of its poles

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

More specifically:

Suppose that $f(z)$ is meromorphic on a disk $\{\lvert z\lvert <s \}$, show that the Laurent decomposition of $f(z)$ on the annulus $\{s-\epsilon<\lvert z\lvert <s\}$ has the form $f_0(z) + f_1(z)$, where $f_1(z)$ is the sum of the principal parts of $f(z)$ at its poles.

Since $f(z)$ is meromorphic, the number of poles it has must be finite. However, I don't know how to define the disks surrounding each pole and add them up... Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As $f$ is meromorphic, it has a finite number of poles with finite orders. Let us say $c_1,\ldots, c_k$ with orders $m_1,\ldots, m_k$. Therefore
$$f(z)\prod_{j=1}^k(z-c_j)^{m_j}$$
is a holomorphic $g(z)\in\mathcal{O}(\{|z|<s\}$. Hence
$$f(z)=g(z)\left(\frac{1}{(z-c_1)^{m_1}}\cdots\frac{1}{(z-c_k)^{m_k}}\right)=g(z)\sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{h=1}^{m_j}\frac{a_{j,h}}{(z-c_j)^{h}}$$
where $a_{j,h}$ are suitable complex numbers.

So, the Laurent series of $f(z)$ is the sum of the Laurent series of $g(z)\frac{a_{j,h}}{(z-c_j)^{h}}$.

The coefficients of the Laurent series of $g(z)\frac{a_{j,h}}{(z-c_j)^{h}}$ can be calculated by integration on every curve surrounding $c_j$, because the function is holomorphic for $z\neq c_j$. On a very small disk around $c_j$, the difference
$$f(z)-\sum_{h=1}^{m_j}g(z)\frac{a_{j,h}}{(z-c_j)^{h}}$$ 
is holomorphic around $c_j$, therefore the principal parts of these two functions around $c_j$ coincide.

And the thesis should follow.

Comment: Hi wisefool, I'm having some trouble understanding your answer.  Could you clarify what $f_0$ and $f_1$ are here?

Comment: It isn't exactly easy to write these two functions in my setting. The idea is that we can find a small disk $D_j=\{|z-c_j|<\epsilon\}$ such that the only pole of $f$ in $D_j$ is $c_j$, therefore in $D_j^*=\{0<|z-c_j|<\epsilon\}$ the principal parts (pp) of $f$ and $\phi_j=\sum_{h=1}^mg(z)a_{j,h}(z-c_j)^{-h}$ coincide. On the other hand, the pp of $\phi_j$ is the same if calculated on $D_j^*$ or on $\{0<|z|<s\}$, because the function $\phi_j$ is holomorphic outside $c_j$. So,the pp of $f$ is the same of the sum of the pp of $\phi_j$ which are the pp of $f$ around each $c_j$.